# Disable Caching in Tomcat Grails

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, groovy

I need to disable caching during development. Currently I have to rerun the `run-app` command every time I make changes to JS or CSS (which takes 5-10 minutes). This legacy project I inherited is using Grails with embedded Tomcat.

Examples online talk about configuring Tomcat within a `eventConfigureTomcat` hook inside the `_Events.groovy` file:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
}
```

but I can't find any documentation on how to apply `cachingAllowed=false`:

```
<Context className="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext"
         cachingAllowed="false">
</Context>
```

Please keep in mind that I'm a complete Java noob - just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's not being cached in the browser - tomcat is serving cached files.

Comment: @quindimildev - yes - however, this is grails running embedded tomcat - so there's only grails config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your Grails version. Starting at 2.3 you need to add `-reloading` e.g.

```
grails -reloading run-app
```

This works for me and serves the changed files, as long as the browser is actually making requests and not caching things itself.

In 3.x this may no longer be needed but there are config options for reloading that may be excluding your js/css. Search the docs for "reloading" for details.

Comment: your are my hero - I am using grails 2.3, so adding -reloading worked (Except I added the flag to the end of the line: `run-app -reloading`)

Comment: i'm running grails 2.2, and recently noticed login.js is no longer accessible even though my other js can be found. will adding -reloading help here? on the tomcat7 server if i clear the cache directory, restart, then i find that it works...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, this is as for as I got with it:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
    def context = tomcat.host.findChild(serverContextPath)
    context.cachingAllowed = false;
}
```

Not sure how to test it though, since this didn't fix the caching issue.

I have since discovered that Grails is caching the files in the dev build, and the community recommends using the `Asset Pipeline Plugin` to better handle revving, uglifying, etc.